# how to embed youtube video using jwplayer without youtube page

Tags: youtube, embed, jwplayer

i have problem with jwplayer

problem if i open video at my script from phone it show youtube video page

how to hide this page and show only my page

my code for jwplayer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("container").setup({
            file:"{$file_url}",
            image: "{$file_image}",
            autostart: "false",
            aboutlink:"http://elfnoon.com",
            abouttext:"elfnoon.CoM Player",
            allowscriptaccess:"always",
            height: {$height},
            width: {$width},
            logo: {
                file: '{$siteurl}/player/logo.png',
                link: '{$siteurl}',
                position: 'bottom.right',
                hide: 'false',
                margin: '-35',
                linktarget: '_blank',
                hide: 'false',
                over: '10',
                out: '0.75'
                },
            wmode:"opaque",
            volume:"100",
            icons:"true",
            bufferlength:"900",
            related: {
                file: '{$siteurl}/jw6-related.xml',
                onclick: 'link'
                        },
            modes:[
                { type:'html5' }
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

[test link](http://212.83.136.205/~elfnon/demo/you/file.php?f=811)

with open page from cumputer it show my script normaly

but if from phone it show youtube page

same friends tell me use api but the script for public videos so not know how to make api for my site to embed video using my player with my settings

i forget , how i test my player using html5 because it show only swf version :( 
same help plz?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JW6, this should work - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

Comment: YouTube comments are not embeddable.